How can I create an Nx command to dynamically generate a library with a given name?
I have a repository called org built with Nx and Angular.
I use the following command to generate a special library, for example, called auth:
npx nx g @nx/angular:lib auth-data-access --directory libs/auth/data-access --buildable --prefix auth --importPath @org/auth/data-access --tags "lib:auth"

If I want to generate another library with a similar structure, such as notification, I replace the auth keyword with notification and run the command again.
My question is, can I create an Nx command that takes a keyword like notification and automatically generates and executes the corresponding command for me?

Have you checked this out: https://nx.dev/recipes/running-tasks/run-commands-executor

You can add an npm script that takes a parameter to run the nx command. In your package.json under scripts add the following:
"generate-data-access": "nx g @nx/angular:lib $npm_config_name-data-access --directory libs/$npm_config_name/data-access --buildable --prefix $npm_config_name --importPath @org/$npm_config_name/data-access --tags 'lib:$npm_config_name'"

On Windows you'll need to replace $npm_config_name with %npm_config_name%
And then run:
npm run generate-data-access --name=notification
